# Python dictionarys and Openpyxl

Tags: python, list, dictionary, openpyxl

Could somebody please explain to me the difference in the following code:

I'm using Openpyxl to iterate over an *.XLSX document (Worksheet column C) and return the cell coordinate from a list (column_names).

```
def get_heading_coordinates():

    for cell in ws['C']:
        for i in range (0, len(column_names)):
            if cell.value == str(column_names[i]):
                sec3_start = cell.offset(1,0).coordinate
                sec3_end = str(cell.offset(-1,0).coordinate)
    print(sec3_end)
```

The results from printing is **C252** which is a cell coordinate. This is working **correctly** for my application.

In the code below I try to make use of a Dictionary.

```
def get_heading_coordinates():
    range_dictionary = {'0': 'cell.offset(1, 0).coordinate', '1': 'cell.offset(-1, 0).coordinate'}
    for cell in ws['C']:
        if cell.value == str(column_names[1]):
            sec3_start = list(range_dictionary.values())[1]
    print(sec3_start)
```

The results from printing is **cell.offset(-1, 0).coordinate** which I understand is the value from the Dictionary. This is working **incorrectly** for my application. What I'm trying to do is assign the variable 'sec3_start' to retrieve the cell coordinate as it does in the first function.

I've tried:

- range_dictionary.values()
- range_dictionary.get(str(1))

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Your dictionary contains strings. It prints strings. It cannot execute the code and get your value because they are strings, not functions. What you should do is eg. store only the `1` and `-1` (the offset values) in the dict and normally execute `cell.offset(range_dictionary[key], 0).coordinate)`.

Comment: Thanks h4ze. I'm trying to avoid doing that as I have 30 variables I need to assign with coordinates, so preferred to store them in a dictionary. 

Is there another way around this?

Comment: You would need to store a function there, but it's more tricky. You know how methods have an "argument" `self`? It usually is "passed" by using the object before the dot, right? But you can also do `ClassName.method_name(object_here, parameter1, parameter2)`. This makes it a normal function where you can pass your object. Therefore, you can do a lambda function that only takes your object that varies through the loop - `cell`.